# Problem with <command> | find in windows which results in "FIND: parameter format incorrect"

Tags: windows, find, pipe

Today I found a strange problem where I can't pass the output of any command to find.
Found this when trying to use `pip list | found /i "pyinstaller"` which resulted in `FIND: formato de parámetros incorrecto` or `FIND: parameter format incorrect`. Then went to the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find) and saw there was nothing wrong with it (apparently) so I decided to try the example that was most similar to mine in the docs (which would be `tasklist | find /v /i "agent"`) and got the same result.

Looked for this behavior but couldn't find anything in particular about it, so it must be a stupid error from my part, so I'm hopping someone can point me out what is that I'm overlooking

P.S. `grep` > `find`, change my mind if you can

Answer (score 1):

You're using PowerShell, I think.  If you used Windows standard command line, it would work.

In PowerShell, it seems that you have to escape the double-quotes:

```
pip list | found /i `"pyinstaller`"
```

see also: https://serverfault.com/questions/758267/powershell-pipe-into-find-exe-command

Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous commenter said the 'find' equivalent for Powershell is 'Select-string' so `netstat -ano -p TCP | select-string '8080'` should do it.